# New FormGroups not being generated when looping array of functions that return a new FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying o generate some preset milestone FormGroups that get generated when and @Input setter recieves a value. First I have an imported file that has functions that return a new FormGroup.

```
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

function pickedUp() {
    return new FormGroup({
        type: new FormControl([{key: '0', name: 'Picked up'}, Validators.required]),
        last_update: new FormControl(new Date),
        status: new FormControl([{key: '0', name: 'planned'}, Validators.required]),
        airport: new FormControl(null),
        airline: new FormControl(null),
        flight_number: new FormControl(null)
    });
}

function droppedToAirport() {
    return new FormGroup({
        type: new FormControl([{key: '1', name: 'Dropped to departure airport'}, Validators.required]),
        last_update: new FormControl(new Date),
        status: new FormControl([{key: 0, name: 'planned'}, Validators.required]),
        airport: new FormControl(null),
        airline: new FormControl(null),
        flight_number: new FormControl(null)
    });
}
```

they are not all listed here as there are many of them :)

Then in the same file I group them all into an array:

```
export const airTrips = [
    pickedUp,
    droppedToAirport,
    departedAirport,
    arrivedAirport,
    departedAirport,
    arrivedAirport,
    departedAirport,
    arrivedAirport,
    outForDelivery,
    delivered
];

export const linehaulTrips = [
    pickedUp,
    droppedToOriginTerminal,
    departedOriginTerminal,
    arrivedDestinationTerminal,
    outForDelivery,
    delivered
];
```

Which Finally gets imported into my component. Looking at the component below, you will see that I have an Input on a setter that then calls the mapMilestones method. The method loops through the above array and calls the function inside FormArray.push(). This should give me a new FormGroup in this FormArray, but it's not. However, I can see if I do something like `console.log(group())` it will generate the new FormGroup for me. Not sure why this one is failing at all!

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Milestone } from 'src/app/models/trips.model';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerServiceLevels, airTrips, linehaulTrips } from './preset-milestones';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-milestones-form',
    templateUrl: './milestones-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./milestones-form.component.scss']
})

export class MilestonesFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() set milestones(val: Milestone[]) {
        if (val) {
            val.forEach(item => this.createMilestone(item));
        }
    }

    @Input() set serviceLevel(val: KeyNamePair) {
        if (val) {
            this.mapMilestonePresets(val.name);
        }
    }

    form: FormGroup;


    get milestonesArray() {
        return this.form.get('milestones') as FormArray;
    }

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            milestones: new FormArray([])
        });
    }


    mapMilestonePresets(serviceLevel: string) {
        if (serviceLevel !== CustomerServiceLevels.linehaul) {
            for (const group of airTrips) {
                this.milestonesArray.push(group());
            }
        } else {
            for (const group of linehaulTrips) {
                this.milestonesArray.push(group());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Comment: Hold that thought, I am working on putting one up!

Comment: so this is strange, it works in StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqrcwi

Comment: Are you getting any error otherwise?

Comment: no other errors. I can only think I have something else going on in the application locally since it works in a VERY simplified version in StackBlitz. I can't put the whold app up there :)

Comment: I think you're confused with FormBuilder a new FormControl. You has, e.g. new FormControl([{key: '0', name: 'planned'}, Validators.required]), the correct construction is new FormControl({key:'0',name:planned},Validators.required) -two arguments-. I supouse you want to use FormBuilder, that's , if you has injected in constructor private fb:FormBuilder, this.fb([{key:'0',name:planned},Validators.required), see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder (anyway you has a FormControl with an object as value -not an string, number,etc... -be carefull-